# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy', tried everything

Tags: python, flask, modulenotfounderror

I have installed flask-sqlalchemy using pip, yet I am seeing this error. I have tried everything but I can't seem to find a solution. I am new to development so pardon me if I am being a little vague, it's just that I am confused myself (I use macOS, if that helps).

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///market.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length = 30), nullable=False, unique=True)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    barcode = db.Column(db.String(length = 12), nullable=False, unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(length = 1000), nullable=False, unique=True)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home_page():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/market')
def market_page():
    items = [
        {'id': 1, 'name': 'Phone', 'barcode': '893212299897', 'price': 500},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'Laptop', 'barcode': '123985473165', 'price': 900},
        {'id': 3, 'name': 'Keyboard', 'barcode': '231985128446', 'price': 150}
    ]
    return render_template('market.html', items=items)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkm5r.png)

I tried uninstalling and installing flask-sqlalchemy and saw almost all the articles on StackOverflow relating to this issue but I don't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Are you running this program in a virtual environment?

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple instances of Python installed? That's happened to me before, where when I pip install something, then try and run it on idle it doesn't run because it's not from the same installation.

Comment: Brock Brown is correct. How *exactly* are you running this script?